# Jquery Twitter Parse Json

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, twitter

I have this issue, where everything is working more or less but its giving me too many results.

Any idea?

```
var url = "search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23ps3&rpp=15&from=mmgn&lang=en&callback=?";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data.results, function(i, item) {
        var tweet = item.text;
        var combinedRegex = /[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&\?\/.=]+|[@]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+|[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g,
            container = $('#tweet-container');
        var result, prevLastIndex = 0;
        combinedRegex.lastIndex = 0;
        while ((result = combinedRegex.exec(tweet))) {
            $('').appendTo('#tweet-container');
            $('').html(tweet.slice(prevLastIndex, result.index)).appendTo('.tweet');
            if (result[0].slice(0, 1) == "@") {
                $('').attr('href', 'http://twitter.com/' + encodeURIComponent(result[0].slice(1))).html(result[0]).appendTo(".tweet");
            } else if (result[0].slice(0, 1) == "#") {
                $('').attr('href', 'http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23' + encodeURIComponent(result[0].slice(1))).html(result[0]).appendTo('.tweet');
            } else {
                $('').attr('href', result[0]).html(result[0]).appendTo(".tweet");
            }
            prevLastIndex = combinedRegex.lastIndex;
        }
        $('').append($('').html(tweet.slice(prevLastIndex)));
    });
});
```

Hyperlink, below

Comment: You can see it running here: http://jsfiddle.net/jp555soul/BUuUE/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of issues here: appending your li elements and inserting your 'first'/'last' span elements.

1) you're calling .appendTo(".tweet"), which is selecting ALL elements with the tweet class.
Instead, create an variable for the li element, and then append your data to that *variable*, eg.

```
var $li = $('<li class="tweet" />');
$li.appendTo('#tweet-container');
...
$('whatever').appendTo($li);
```

2) On your span elements, you are also appending to ALL .tweet elements (as above).  It appears you want to add a span element only to the first and last item in your list.  If this is the case, I'd suggest waiting until the loop is done and then wrapping the first and last elements like:

```
$('li',container).first().wrapInner('<span class="first"/>').end().last().wrapInner('<span class="last"/>');
```

Here's the [changed code](http://jsfiddle.net/cnGWc/).

You could also stand to make your jquery a bit more efficient, but that's beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Thanks I got it to work and this was my result: http://jsfiddle.net/jp555soul/BUuUE/3/